# Neural Networks: A step-by-step breakdown of the Backpropagation phase?

Tags: neural-network, backpropagation

I have to design an animated visual representation of a neural network that is functional (i.e. with UI that allows you to tweak values etc). The primary goal with it is to help people visualize how and when the different math operations are performed in a slow-motion, real-time animation.  I have the visuals set up along with the UI that allows you to tweak values and change the layout of the neurons, as well as the visualizations for the feed forward stage, but since I don’t actually specialize in neural networks at all, I’m having trouble figuring out the best way to visualize the back propagation phase- mainly due to the fact that I’ve had trouble figuring out the exact order of operations during this stage.

The visualization starts by firing neurons forward, and then after that chain of fired neurons reach an output, an animation shows the difference between the actual and predicted values, and from this point I want to visualize the network firing backwards while demonstrating the math that is taking place. But this is where I really am unsure about what exactly is supposed to happen.

So my questions are:

- Which weights are actually adjusted in the backpropagation phase? Are all of the weights adjusted throughout the entire neural network, or just the ones that fired during the forward pass?
- Are all of the weights in each hidden layer adjusted by the same amount during this phase, or are they adjusted by a value that is offset by their current weight, or some other value? It didn't really make sense to me that they would all be adjusted by the same amount, without being offset by a curve or something of the sort.

I’ve found a lot of great information about the feed forward phase online, but when it comes to the backpropagation phase I’ve had a lot of trouble finding any good visualizations/explanations about what is actually happening during this phase.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Which weights are actually adjusted in the back-propagation phase? Are all of the weights adjusted throughout the entire neural network, or just the ones that fired during the forward pass?

It depends on how you build the neural network, typically you forward-propagate your network first, and then back-propagate, in the back-propagation phase, the weights are adjusted based on the error and Sigmoid derivative. It is up to you to choose which weights are adjusted, as well as the type of structure that you have. For a simple Perceptron network (based on what I know) every weight would be adjusted.

> Are all of the weights in each hidden layer adjusted by the same amount during this phase, or are they adjusted by a value that is offset by their current weight, or some other value? It didn't really make sense to me that they would all be adjusted by the same amount, without being offset by a curve or something of the sort.

Back-propagation slightly depends on the type of structure you are using. You usually use some kind of algorithm - usually a gradient descent or stochastic gradient descent to control how much a weight is adjusted. From what I know, in a Perceptron network every weight is adjusted by it's own value.

In conclusion, a back-propagation is just a way to adjust the weights so that the output values are closer to the desired result. It might also help you to look in to gradient descent, or [watch a network being built from scratch](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kft1AJ9WVDk) (I learned how to build neural networks through breaking them down step-by-step).

**Here is my own version of a step-by-step break down of back-propagation:**

1. The error is calculated based on the difference between the actual outputs and the expected outputs.
2. The adjustments matrix/vector is calculated by finding the dot product of the error matrix/vector and the Sigmoid derivative of training inputs.
3. The adjustments are applied to the weights.
4. Steps 1 - 3 are iterated many times until the actual outputs are close to the expected outputs.

EXT. In a more complicated neural network you might use stochastic gradient descent or gradient descent to find the best adjustments for the weights.

Edit on Gradient Descent:

Gradient descent, also known as the network derivative, is a method of finding a good adjustment value to change your weights in back-propagation.

Gradient Descent Formulae: f(X) = X * (1 - X)

Gradient Descent Formulae (Programmatic):

[image: Gradient Descent Formulae Programmatic]

Gradient Descent Explanation:

Gradient descent is a method which involves finding the best adjustment to a weight. It is necessary so that the best weight values can be found. During the back-propagation iteration, the further the actual output is from the expected output, the bigger the change to the weights is. You can imagine it as an inverted hill, and in each iteration, the ball rolling down the hill goes faster and then slower as it reaches the bottom.

[image: Diagram]
*Credit to Clairvoyant.*

Stochastic gradient descent is a more advanced method used when the best weight value is harder to find than in the use case of a standard gradient descent example. This might not be the best explanation, so for a much clearer explanation, [refer to this video.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sDv4f4s2SB8) For a clear explanation of stochastic gradient descent, [refer to this video.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vMh0zPT0tLI)

Comment: Thanks for the speedy response :) Also, I tried to open the link you provided but it appears to be broken. You're explanation is awesome, and very simple to understand, so after feeling as though I've been drowning in the jargon that seems to be so deeply rooted in most subject matter pertaining to Neural Networks, your response is very refreshing, so thank you for that.

When you say that a gradient descent or stochastic gradient descent is typically used to control how much a weight is adjusted, do you have an example of one of these gradient descent formulas where w = weight?

Comment: @AlexBianchini I fixed the link in my response. Also gradient descent is more of a concept and doesn't really have any exact formula. However it is also called the derivative of the network, so I can give a formula for that;

 f(x) = x * (1 - x) 

I also included a more detailed response about this as an edit in my question, btw I am trying to get more reputation, so I would appreciate it if you would upvote and accept my answer! :D

Comment: @JamesBarnett Couldn't also calculate the gradient without backpropagation? Is backpropagation lighter in terms of computational cost from other methods?

Comment: @adosar The methods I listed are just a few methods to determine backpropagation, there are many other ways to determine the gradient. Generally though, any method used to find the gradient and adjust weights is called back-propagation as you are still going propagating backwards in the network and adjusting weights accordingly.

Comment: @adosar I am sure you are right, there probably are better methods to calculating the gradient, but gradient descent and stochastic gradient descent are probably one of the easiest to recognise and understand. Some methods are faster than others, some are more accurate, a few examples of other methods you might be able to try are simulated annealing or adam's method.

Comment: @JamesBarnett What I had in my mind is why for example we use backpropagation (chain rule) to calculate gradient? If our loss function is analytic then why not just directly compute the partial derivatives with respect to weights? Why we need to invoke chain rule?