# How does the Gradient function work in Backpropagation?

Tags: deep-learning, neural-network, gradient-descent

In backpropagation, is the gradient of Loss w.r.t layer L calculated using gradient w.r.t. layer L-1? Or, is the gradient of Loss w.r.t. layer L-1 calculated using the gradient w.r.t layer L?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A gradient descent function is used in back-propagation to find the best value to adjust the weights by. There are two common types of gradient descent: `Gradient Descent`, and `Stochastic Gradient Descent`.

Gradient descent is a function that determines the best adjustment value to change the weights by. Over each iteration, it determines the volume/amount the weights should be adjusted by, the further away from the best determined weight, the bigger the adjustment value will be. You can think of it as a ball rolling down a hill; the ball's velocity being the adjustment value, and the hill being the possible adjustment values. Essentially, you want the ball (adjustment value) to be closest to the bottom of the world (possible adjustment) as possible. The ball's velocity will increase until it reaches the bottom of the hill - the bottom of the hill is the best possible value.
[image: Practical Image]
A more practical explanation can be found [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gradient_descent).

Stochastic gradient descent is a more complicated version of the gradient descent function and it is used in a neural network that may have a false-best adjustment value, where regular gradient descent won't find the best value, but a value it think's is the best. This can be analogised as the ball rolling down two hills, the hills are different in height. It rolls down the first hill and reaches the bottom of the first hill, thinking that it's reached the best possible answer, but with stochastic gradient descent, it would know that the position it was in now was not the best position, but in reality, the bottom of the second hill.

The left is what gradient descent would output.
The right is what the stochastic gradient descent would find (the best possible value).
[image: Practical diagram]
A more descriptive and practical version of this explanation can be found [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stochastic_gradient_descent).

And finally to conclude my answer to your question, in back-propagation you calculate the furthest right weight-matrix's gradient and then adjust the weights accordingly, then you move one layer to the left, `L-1`, (on the next weight-matrix) and repeat the step, so in other words you determine the gradient, adjust accordingly and then move the the left.

I have also talked about this in detail in another question, it might help to [check that one out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65922410/neural-networks-a-step-by-step-breakdown-of-the-backpropagation-phase/65922962#65922962).

Comment: Thanks! However, what would be the answer to this - > In backpropagation, is the gradient of Loss w.r.t layer L calculated using gradient w.r.t. layer L-1? Or, is the gradient of Loss w.r.t. layer L-1 calculated using the gradient w.r.t layer L?

Comment: @AnubhavSachdev I am not entirely sure what you are asking? Do you mean,`How do you calculate Gradient of Loss?`

Comment: During backpropagation, when we calculate the Gradient of the weight matrix at any given Layer L, what is the order of the process? Do we first calculate gradient of the previous layer(L-1) and then the current layer (L) or do we calculate the gradient at the current layer(L) and then calculate it for the previous layer (L-1) ?

Comment: So the order of process for back propagation is as follows: firstly you forward-propagate your network, as you would normally, then you back-propagate, this is in the reverse direction of the forward-propagation (backwards) so from right to left. You start at the end layer and find the gradient for that layer and accordingly adjust the weights, then you go to the next layer (in this case the one next to the left) and repeat, so yes. You calculate the gradient of the current layer, adjust the weights, and then move to the  layer before the current layer (`L-1`). I will include this in my answer

Comment: @AnubhavSachdev I hope I answered your question, if you are happy with my response, please upvote my answer and accept it!

Comment: Just a follow-up question, In a single forward-backward pass, do the weights and biases of all layers get updated or just one layer?

Comment: @AnubhavSachdev It is dependant on the type of network. In a typical feed-forward single layer perceptron network (to my understanding), all of the layers' weight matrices are propagated. So in your case, yes, all of the weights are updated.

Answer (score 2):

The gradient of L wrt layer l−1 is calculated using the gradient wrt layer l

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I do not see how this answers the question at the top of this page, but it should. Please [edit] according to [answer] or delete the answer. Otherwise it risks being flagged as "not an answer" and being deleted.

Answer (score 0):

In short,

Feedforward works from **Left Layer** to **Right Layer**

Backpropagation works from **Right Layer** to **Left Layer** to update the weights and biases of all layers so that cost is minimised. In each iteration, we calculate the loss and update the weights and biases.