# How does multiplying matrices in backpropagation work

Tags: python, matrix, neural-network, backpropagation

I'm new to neural networks and im tasked to create my own neural network in python. So far i've managed to create layers with their own weights, outputs, and derivatives. I'm currently working on the back propagation process and i'm having some trouble with it. Here is the current logic i have for my algorithm. In the picture, assume '*' as element wise multiplication like np.multiply. ydtf is the derivate from each node of each layer and weights are the weight connections that each nodes received from the layer before it. I'm sorry if the transposes are wrong.

[image]

It turns out, i've found out why my backpropagation dimensions are wrong :

[image]

Question is, is this logic correct? if not, what do i have to do to automate backpropagation exactly? does this process rely on the comparison between how many nodes each layer has?

Answer (score 1):

Your question is referring to back-propagation, but you seem to be describing forward-propagation, *(if this is a mistake check the bottom of my answer for more details)*.

Imagine we have a neural network with 5 input nodes, 3 neuron nodes and 1 output node. All of these nodes are connected with weights (lines).

[image: Neural Network Diagram]

To create the matrix for the Neuron array we will have to loop through each neuron in our network. Let's take N <sub>0</sub> for example.

The equation for N <sub>0</sub> will be **N<sub>0</sub> = (I <sub>0</sub> * W <sub>0</sub>) + (I<sub>1</sub> * W <sub>1</sub>) + (I<sub>2</sub> * W <sub>2</sub>) + (I<sub>3</sub> * W <sub>3</sub>) + (I<sub>4</sub> * W <sub>4</sub>)**.

This is the easiest way I can present it in an equation. The simplest way put is this - the value for the next matrix is equal to the sum of all the weights and inputs going into that neuron.

*Bear in mind that this is merely a simple equation, excluding any kind of bias or activation function, etc.*

Your question wasn't quite clear and so I might have mis-interpreted what you said. If my answer has not rectified your question then please check out some of my previous answers which may help.

[Does Back Propagation and Gradient Descent use the same logic?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66203158/does-back-propagation-and-gradient-descent-use-the-same-logic/66205984#66205984)

[How does the Gradient function work in Backpropagation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66035281/how-does-the-gradient-function-work-in-backpropagation/66035597#66035597)

I hope one of these responses answers your question, have a good day!