# Confusion in Backpropagation

Tags: neural-network, backpropagation

I've started working on Forward and back propagation of neural networks. I've coded it as-well and works properly too. But i'm confused in the algorithm itself. I'm new to Neural Networks.
So Forward propagation of neural networks is finding the right label with the given weights?
and Back-propagation is using forward propagation to find the most error free parameters by minimizing cost function and using these parameters to help classify other training examples? And this is called a trained Neural Network?
I feel like there is a big blunder in my concept if there is please let me know where i'm wrong and why i am wrong.

Comment: Somewhat. A question like this will get a better response on stats (cross validated) https://stats.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @AndrewHolmgren cant post there right now there is a cooldown before you can post. If i dont get a response i'll delete here and ask there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will try my best to explain forward and back propagation in a detailed yet simple to understand manner, although it's not an easy topic to do.

**Forward Propagation**

Forward propagation is the process in a neural network where-by during the runtime of the network, values are fed into the front of the neural network, (the inputs). You can imagine that these values then travel across the weights which multiply the original value from the inputs by themselves. They then arrive at the hidden layer (neurons). Neurons vary quite a lot based on different types of networks, but here is one way of explaining it. When the values reach the neuron they go through a function where every single value being fed into the neuron is summed up and then fed into an activation function. This activation function can be very different depending on the use-case but let's take for example a linear activation function. It essentially gets the value being fed into it and then it rounds it to a 0 or 1. It is then fed through more weights and then it is spat out into the outputs. Which is the last step into the network.

You can imagine this network with this diagram.

[image: Neural Network Diagram]

**Back Propagation**

Back propagation is just like forward propagation except we work backwards from where we were in forward propagation.

The aim of back propagation is to reduce the error in the training phase (trying to get the neural network as accurate as possible). The way this is done is by going backwards through the weights and layers.  At each weight the error is calculated and each weight is individually adjusted using an optimization algorithm; optimization algorithm is exactly what it sounds like. It optimizes the weights and adjusts their values to make the neural network more accurate.

Some optimization algorithms include gradient descent and stochastic gradient descent. I will not go through the details in this answer as I have already explained them in some of my other answers (linked below).

The process of calculating the error in the weights and adjusting them accordingly is the back-propagation process and it is usually repeated many times to get the network as accurate as possible. The number of times you do this is called the `epoch count`. It is good to learn the importance of how you should manage epochs and batch sizes (another topic), as these can severely impact the efficiency and accuracy of your network.

I understand that this answer may be hard to follow, but unfortunately this is the best way I can explain this. It is expected that you might not understand this the first time you read it, but remember this is a complicated topic. I have a linked a few more resources down below including a video (not mine) that explains these processes even better than a simple text explanation can. But I also hope my answer may have resolved your question and have a good day!

**Further resources:**

[Link 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66203158/does-back-propagation-and-gradient-descent-use-the-same-logic/66205984#66205984) - Detailed explanation of back-propagation.

[Link 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66035281/how-does-the-gradient-function-work-in-backpropagation/66035597#66035597) - Detailed explanation of stochastic/gradient-descent.

[Youtube Video 1](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8bNIkfRJZpo) - Detailed explanation of types of propagation.
*Credits go to Sebastian Lague*